# Best practices for IPv4/IPv6 hosts in DNS zones?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, best-practices

I've got a VPS with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and I'd like to use them both for my website and other services I might use. I've added a "www" register both with "A" and "AAAA", and I've done the same for the "ns" register. Is this "the Right Way", or should I use different names for the IPv6 part? (i.e., "www6", "ns6", etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, it depends on what you want.

If you're using both protocols (v4 and v6) to offer the same service (eg IMAP/S, or HTTP, or whatever), and you want clients to be protocol-transparent - that is to say, if you want v6-enabled clients to use v6, and others to use v4, and no-one to care about which they're using - then use the same hostname in each record.

If you want people to be able to select protocol by hostname, use different hostnames for A and AAAA records.

So, for my webserver, where I want clients to be protocol-agnostic, I use the same hostname:

```
www.teaparty.net.   3600    IN  A   178.18.123.145
www.teaparty.net.   3600    IN  AAAA    2a01:8000:0:4::1:1
```

For my ntp pool server, where I decided I'd like people to be able to select the protocol, I used different ones:

```
ntp.teaparty.net.   3600    IN  A   178.18.123.148
ntp6.teaparty.net.  3600    IN  AAAA    2a01:8000:0:4::123:123
```

Work out what client behaviour you wish to encourage, and make policy accordingly.